# Laptop durability criterias

Tags: laptop, durability

I am looking for a laptop for almost 24/7 operation in a hot environment (Greece).

What are the criteria describing durable laptop? Metal body seems obvious, but anything else? Of course there are rugged laptops like Toughbook, but it's not an option because of cost.

Comment: But a metal body isn't very nice in hot enviroments because the whole body feels super hot in that case. I would think white ABS laptops are best, but since I live in Belgium and don't have a lot of experience with hot weather, please take it with a grain of salt

Comment: Are you suggesting a metal body in the hope that it will radiate more heat, because its running 24/7?

Comment: Adding a cost range will improve this question.  Please specify currency.